Отладчик пропускает шаги итерации
Отладчик пропускает шаги итерации. В указанном куске кода, Я искал ошибку(уже исправил). Но Я потратил больше времени, чем хотелось, потому-что отладчик пропускал шаги итерации. Переменная j от 0 сразу доходила до 3, пропуская значения 1 и 2. Но после 2-3 повторных попыток, отладчик работает адекватно. Порой отладчик, вместо шага просто выполняет весь код целиком (другие части кода). Сборка Debug, VS22, ОС Windows 11.
С чем это связано и как это исправить?
for(int i = 0; i < Result.Rows; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < Result.Columns; j++) {
        if(j >= M1.Columns) {
            Result[i, j] = M2[i, j-M1.Columns];
        }
        else {
            Result[i,j] = M1[i, j];
        }
    }
}


С чем это связано и как это исправить? - с неполными знаниями о том, как пользоваться отладчиком. Исправить так: читайте документацию https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour обратите внимание на разницу между действиями "Шаг с заходом" и "Шаг с обходом".

Я знаю, как использовать отладчиком, нажимал на F11 ( шаг с заходом). К тому же вне зависимости от типа шага, должен происходить именно, что шаг, а не скачок.

Убедитесь что в профиле сборки галочка "оптимизация кода" не стоит. Ну или в том что вы используетс профиль Debug, а не Release.

Я уже написал в самом вопросе, что режим у меня Debug, в свойствах стоит оптимизация только для версии Release

Магии не существует. Ничего необычного в вашем коде нет. Остальное покрыто завесой тайн.

Вот поэтому и был задан этот вопрос

Создайте новый проект, скопируйте туда кусок показанного кода, запустите его там. Убедитесь что проблема воспроизводится. После чего отредактируйте вопрос и добавьте туда: 1) запускаемый код целиком, 2) содержимое файла проекта .csproj. Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

Данная проблема мучает меня уже неделю в разных проектах от веба до консольных приложений.

На ваш вопрос невозможно дать ответ. Почему? Все просто! Мы не сидим у вас за спиной и не знаем что вы пишете, как вы пишете, что за софт используете (имею ввиду всякие плагины, настройки в нем и др. изменения), ну и куча других аспектов, которые можете узнать только вы. И пальцем вас ткнуть в нужное тоже невозможно, ибо мы не являемся авторами VS. Единственное, что лично я могу посоветовать, так это сбросить VS до заводского состояния. Если не помогает, то стоит написать в тех. поддержку IDE и пусть Microsoft скажут что и как вам стоит делать.
